# Different ways to define resources in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

Fairly new (couple of days) to WPF development and C#. Looking for a high-level philosophical difference between two ways of defining and accessing application resources from XAML:

- I can define resources in a .resx file in the visual editor and then read them in a XAML file like `<TextBox Text="{x:Static p:Resources.name}">` (provided the "p" namespace points to the application Properties).
- Or I can define resources anywhere in my control hierarchy like, say, `<sys:String x:Key="name">Name</sys:String>` and then reference them as `<TextBox Text="{StaticResource name}">`

When and why would I want to prefer one over the other?

Comment: You will notice the difference when you come to the point to localize your application to multiple languages. In case you use the .resx you just need to add resource assemblies (WPF finds and loads them automatically). This magic is done via the ResourceManager. There is no such magic for XAML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources of this type:

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static p:Resources.name}">
```

Usually used instead of the system registry, that is, there store some metadata applications that can change the user, such as background color, some settings, etc.

`Example`

Binding default value from XAML:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WorkWithSettings.Properties"

<Button Width="100" Height="30"
        Background="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Setting, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Set value from code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.Setting = "#FF007CE4";
}
```

As mentioned in the comments `@gomi42`, this type of resource is used to localize the application. Here:

[`WPF Localization for Dummies`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies)

[`Sample for globalization and localization in WPF`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18548/Sample-for-globalization-and-localization-in-WPF)

You can see an example of this implementation.

The resources of this type:

```
<sys:String x:Key="name">Name</sys:String>
```

Are constants and are meant they do not change throughout the life of the application (not including [`DynamicResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). I keep it there window sizes that do not change, and other strings of window headers.